# How to build a App and ask for pin just in the first time that the app start - React Nactive

Tags: react-native

I have doubts. Please I need help

I will try to explain in the best way

I want to make my application as follows:

The first time she initializes, she asks for a pin. to print the pin to keep the server that i call "token". This token must to be saved for a lifetime even after you have opened an application to receive a token then once you can open an application to see the following:

if you already have a token, then no longer ask for the pin otherwise, ask for the pin and save the return token. such as a watsup app that once entered a phone number, if the number becomes then never ask for the number again, if the forum then starts the registration process asking for the phone number.

here is my code below.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, Button, TextInput, Alert,         
AsyncStorage,TouchableWithoutFeedback,Keyboard} from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';
import MenuPrincipal from './MenuPrincipal';

const myStyle = {
principal: {
    paddingTop: 17,
    paddingLeft: 2,
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
},
caixa: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    height: 300,
    borderWidth: 1,
    width: 300,
    borderColor: 'black',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderRadius: 20,
},
inputPin: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    width: 290,
    height: 40,
    borderRadius: 15,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'black',
    marginTop: 60,
    marginBottom: 30,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    fontSize: 20,
    //paddingLeft:20,
    color: 'black',
    textAlign: 'center'
    },
    bemVindo: {
        fontSize: 40,
        marginBottom: 20,
    },
    botao: {
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    texto:     {
        textAlign: 'center',
        fontSize: 20,
        color: 'black',
        backgroundColor: 'white',
    }
    }

    export default class PaginaInicial extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {codigoPin: null,
            dados: [],
            tokenLocal: null,
            user: null,
            session: null,
        };

    }
       componentWillMount(){
          //AsyncStorage.removeItem('localData', () => {
       let resultTemp;
           AsyncStorage.getItem('localData', (err, result) => {
               resultTemp = JSON.parse(result);

           if(resultTemp !== null){
               this.setState({tokenLocal: resultTemp.User.Session.token});
               console.log('token: ',this.state.tokenLocal);
               //this.setState(this.state.session, resultTemp.User.Session);
               //this.setState(this.state.user, resultTemp.User);
               //this.setState(this.state.dados, resultTemp);
           }
           //this.setState({tokenLocal: resultTemp.User.Session.token})
   });
   console.log('token no else', this.state.tokenLocal);
}
    HttpRequest(){
        {this.props.navigator.push({id: 'MenuPrincipal'})}
    };
   render(){
       console.log('token no render: ',this.state.tokenLocal);
       let token = AsyncStorage.getItem(this.state.tokenLocal);
        //let session = AsyncStorage.getItem(this.state.session);
        //let user = AsyncStorage.getItem(this.state.user);
        //let dados = AsyncStorage.getItem(this.state.dados);

       const {principal, caixa, inputPin, bemVindo, botao, texto} = myStyle;
       if(this.state.tokenLocal=== null){
       //if(true){
           return(

               <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={()=>{Keyboard.dismiss()}}>
              <View style={principal}>
                   <View style={caixa}>
                       <Text style={bemVindo}>Bem Vindo</Text>
                       <Text style={texto}>Para que possamos identificar-            
   lhe, Indique a baixo o código pin</Text>
                   <TextInput placeholder='Código da Loja' style={inputPin}
                              onChangeText={(text) => 
   this.setState({codigoPin: text})} clearButtonMode={'while-editing'}
                   />
                   <Button title='Continuar' style={botao} onPress={() =>  {
                       this.HttpRequest();
                   }}
                   />
               </View>
           </View>
           </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
       );
   } else {
       return(
           <Text>{this.props.navigator.push({id: 'MenuPrincipal'})}</Text>
       );
    }

  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is the logic of getting a token and then saving it. The rest is mostly navigation and UI/UX. Please have a look at this example of getting a json web token with react native using a python backend in google appengine. Note that the user must be registered first, you can do this from a second screen.

```
  login() {
        const {
            email,
            password,
            token
        } = this.state;


        fetch('https://www.<MY-APP>.com/account/mob_login', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                "email": this.state.email,
                "password": this.state.password,
            }),
        }).then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                this.setAuth_id(responseJson.auth_id);
                this.setName(responseJson.email);
                this.setToken(responseJson.token);
                Alert.alert(
                    'Welcome ' + responseJson.email,
                    'You are now logged in',
                    [

                        {text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed')},
                        {text: 'Logout', onPress: () => AsyncStorage.clear()},
                    ],
                    {cancelable: false}
                );
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    }
```

The password is in this case equivalent to your PIN. You can then save it in AsyncStorage for the lifetime of the app or until you log out a user.

You can find my complete code for this at my repository www.github.com/montao/trending-ads-native

For completeness, this is how the backend works to create and deliver the token:

```
  def post(self):
        self.response.headers.add_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        self.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS'
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
        email = json.loads(self.request.body)['email']
        password = json.loads(self.request.body)['password']

        try:
            user1 = self.auth.get_user_by_password(email, password)
            encoded = jwt.encode({'username': user1.email}, 'secret', algorithm='HS256')
            dic = {}
            dic['token'] = encoded
            dic['email'] = user1.email
            dic['auth_id'] = email # update later
            self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
            self.response.write(webapp2_extras.json.encode(dic))

        except (Exception), e:
            # Returns error message to self.response.write in the BaseHandler.dispatcher
            # Currently no message is attached to the exceptions
            self.redirect(webapp2.uri_for('home'))
```